# What to put in front of a future role or title

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the antonym of "ex-": a word to put in front of roles or titles that the mentioned person will hold later in life.

For example:
In 1982 I met ???? president Clinton.
The expression "Sunlight is the best of disinfectants" was coined before World War I by ???? associate justice Louis Brandeis.

Would "future" work? Or "subsequent"? Or is there a better word or prefix or phrase?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can say *the future President Clinton* and *the future associate justice Louis Brandeis*.

Comment: "To-be President Clinton" and "Clinton, who would become president in 1993" or similar phrasing might give you a marginally better control in describing the sequence of events.

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin     Yes, I would prefer 'President-to-be Clinton'. But I think 'future' is better. A young school-leaver working in Barkers' store in Kensington, was urged by the management not to take up his place at Oxford University, but to accept a post with them as a trainee manager. The young man in question decided he would rather go to university. He would later win three British General Elections, each with massive majorities. Barkers had been employing the future Prime Minister, Tony Blair as a furniture-removal labourer!

Comment: @WS2 So he was involved with Labour from a young age then? :)

Comment: @anotherdave Yes, in between Fettes College and reading jurisprudence at St John's College, Oxford, the 'future Prime Minister' was briefly both a rock musician, and a member of the labouring class!